# Java, replace string numbers with blankstring and remove everything after the numbers

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have strings like:

```
Alian 12WE
```

and

```
ANI1451
```

Is there any way to replace all the numbers (and everything after the numbers) with an empty string in JAVA?

I want the output to look like this:

```
Alian

ANI
```

Comment: Use regular expression to search the first index of number and then use `substring(0,index)` .. google it on how to use regex in java and substring method. Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a regex, it's pretty simple:

```
public class Test {

    public static String replaceAll(String string) {
        return string.replaceAll("\\d+.*", "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceAll("Alian 12WE"));
        System.out.println(replaceAll("ANI1451"));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to remove everyting after a digit is found - something like:

```
String s = "Alian 12WE";
s = s.replaceAll("\\d+.*", "");
```

- `\\d+` finds one or more consecutive digits
- `.*` matches any characters after the digits

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex

```
"Alian 12WE".split("\\d")[0] // Splits the string at numbers, get the first part.
```

Or replace `"\\d.+$"` with `""`

Comment: Add `.trim()` to remove trailing spaces

Comment: Look at the example output: `Alian `